# Trying to Match / Test for fully qualified sub.domain.com:1000 or 127.0.0.1:1000

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match at the very least required `sub.domain.com` or anything qualifying there in such as dashes, numbers, and so on. But could potentially match/test true for something like for the sake of example.

www2.sub.doh-mein.com

www.sub1-2.doh-mein3.com

sub.domain.com

www2.sub.doh-mein.com:32000

www.sub1-2.doh-mein3.com:32000

sub.domain.com:32000

123.456.789.321

123.456.789.321:32000

My first attempt got me to something that work sort of well, but not entirely which that pattern is/was `/^([a-z0-9-.]+)(:\d{1,5})?$/i` to which I found myself later with

`^((([a-z0-9|-]+\.)*)([a-z0-9|-]+\.)([a-z]+))(:\d{1,5})?$`

Which ends up being an over glorified version of the former. That said is there any means of which I can require a specific minimum of sorts while everything else is optional. The minimums being either `sub.domain.com` or an ip address formated string. From which where I don't have multiple regex patterns running over the same string in hopes of not polluting my code too much otherwise with a bunch of if-else logic

Answer (score 0):

```
/(\w+(\.\w+)+|\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3})(:\d+)?/
```

- `\w+(\.\w+)+` matches `www2.sub.doh-mein.com`, `sub.domain.com`
- `\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}` matches `123.456.789.321`
- `(:\d+)?` matches an optional port  e.g. `:32000`

Performance might be improved by putting `?:` at the start of brackets to indicate you do not want to back reference them:

```
/(?:\w+(?:\.\w+)+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?::\d+)?/
```